# Unsure How to Properly Use Swing Layouts

Tags: java, swing, button, layout

Sorry for vague title, couldn't think of anything better. I'm trying to create a jswing application that has 4 buttons, and three boxes for images. On the left would be four buttons. First "SalesTop", Second "SalesBottom", Third "Preliminary", and Fourth "Next". The right would have three boxes of equal size that I can insert an image into, along with being able to set text next to it to distinguish what each picture is. I have tried looking but I cannot seem to get the layouts to work as I wanted.
This is what I have so far.

```
private JButton salesTop, salesBottom, preliminary, next;
private JLabel current;
private JPanel salesTopEx, salesBottomEx, preliminaryEx, buttonPanel;
private JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();

 public  int CreateJPANEL() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 1000));

    salesTop = new JButton("salesTop");
    salesBottom = new JButton("salesBottom");
    preliminary = new JButton("Preliminary");

    salesTop.addActionListener(new ButtonListener("salesTop"));
    salesBottom.addActionListener(new ButtonListener("salesBottom"));
    preliminary.addActionListener(new ButtonListener("Preliminary"));

    buttonPanel.add(salesTop);
    buttonPanel.add(salesBottom);
    buttonPanel.add(preliminary);

    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainFrame.add(buttonPanel);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    mainFrame.getContentPane();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a `JPanel` with `BoxLayout` for the `JButtons`. Set the `BoxLayout` to vertical.
2. For the images, given the images are the same size, you can just add the `ImageIcon` to a `JLabel`, *along* with text. You can align the text with respect to the `ImageIcon` anywhere you like by using `label.setHorizontalTextPosition` and `label.setVertialTextPosition`. If the images are different size, you can search SO, there are a few good answers on how to scale `ImageIcons`. You can also use a `JPanel` with `BoxLayout` for these `JLabel`. Or maybe better a `GridLayout`
3. Just wrap those two `JPanel` in another `JPanel` with `BorderLayout`. You can place either one at `BorderLayout.CENTER` and depending on which one is `CENTER` put the other one either `WEST` or `EAST`

The key is to take advantage of nesting `JPanels` with different layout managers. You can nest as many `JPanel` as you need.

See more at [Laying out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Here's an example

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class NestJPanels {

    ImageIcon icon;

    public NestJPanels() {
        try {
            icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://sstatic.net/programmers/img/apple-touch-icon.png"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NestJPanels.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            box.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
            box.add(new JButton("Button"));
        }

        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
            label.setBorder(new MatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.GRAY));
            label.setText("StackOverflow");
            imagePanel.add(label);
        }

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.add(box, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(imagePanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NestJPanels.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                new NestJPanels();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that nesting JPanels was possible.